# Hibernate - How to remove entity from parent when deleting child

Tags: java, hibernate, junit, associations

The following code is not working

```java
        User user = new User();
        Project project = new Project();
        project.setOwner(user);

        projectRepository.delete(project);

        assertEquals(0, user.getProjects().size());
```

How should I configure the associations in order to achieve this?

Currently I have

```java
public class User {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "owner")
    private Set<Project> projects = new HashSet<Project>();
}
```

```java
public class Project {
    @ManyToOne
    private User owner;
}
```

The test returns

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected :0
Actual   :1
```

Answer (score 0):

In a one-to-many relationship you should cascade deleting from parent to the child and not the other way around. What will happen in your scenario if you have 3 projects owned by the same user? You delete one of the projects but you cannot delete the user right? Because he has 2 more projects.

Check this nice article on the subject:
https://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-jpa-and-hibernate-cascade-types/
(The author actually answers lots of questions about hibenrate here)

Comment: I do not want to cascade deleting. I want to remove the project from the user list but the user still needs to exists. I want to avoid removing from all OneToMany that points to a project.